# How to read a java file from Android compiled source

Tags: android

Is there a way in which can I read a file from android source code?

```
my directory structure is as below : 
d:/AndroidApps/MyApp/app/src/main/java/com/mypackage/CameraTest/CameraActivity.java
```

Now I need to read the file `CameraActivity.java` for some string .

Is it possible in Android ? Is there a way in which can I achieve this.

Edit:
My requirement is to read a java file  present under src directory of project structure and parse that file for some string present in that file not String's value.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. Do you want compiled Java code running on Android to access its own source code? Do you just want to get the value of a String defined in `CameraActivity` class? Do you want to decompile somebody else's code?

Comment: My requirement is to read a java file  present under src directory of project structure and parse that file for some string present in that file not String's value.I want to read a file from my own source code.

Comment: Just open it up in your editor and read it with your eyes?

Comment: See, I need to read a java file from src directory when my app is running . Is there  a way in which can I acheive this.

Comment: "Now I need to read the file CameraActivity.java for some string" -- you appear to be running Windows. You are welcome to write some program for Windows that an open that Java source file and do something with it, then run that program on your Windows-based development machine. "Is it possible in Android?" -- you appear to be running Windows, not Android. There is no `d:/` drive in Android (or any other non-Microsoft OS that I can think of). "I need to read a java file from src directory when my app is running" -- there is no `src` directory on your Android device.

Comment: Thanks  a lot mate  .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will not be able to read any compiled file present inside the Android built or from src folder because no such folder will be available once application get's installed on device.

But yes if that file is present as an resource in **assets folder** of android then you can access that file.